# Download PDF in javascript not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, firefox, download

This part is supposed to download a PDF. It work's perfectly in Chrome and Edge but it doesn't work in Firefox.

```
var blob = new Blob(
[base64ToArrayBuffer(response.DocumentBytes)],
{ type: "application/pdf" }
);

var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.download = response.DocumentName;
link.click();
```

Any idea how to fix this issue without breaking the Chrome/Edge download?

Answer (score 1):

Append link to body before calling `link.click()`:

```
document.body.appendChild(link);
```